# Removing white space before and after a character

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My data looks like

```
ID     DATA
1     abc - abc
2     efg - efg
```

now i want to remove the white space before and after '-'

final result will be

```
ID     DATA
1     abc-abc
2     efg-efg
```

any ideas?

Comment: is it always 1 space on each side ?

Comment: None of the query are technically correct.you have to split each value ,apply trim and concatenate back.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use

```
DECLARE @temp1 varchar(1000)
SET @temp1 = 'abc - abc'

SELECT replace( @temp1 , ' - ', '-' )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
update table_name set data = REPLACE(data, ' - ', '-')
```

Comment: This would also remove any other whitespace in the column.. But better after edit :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with replace function:

```
Select ID, REPLACE(DATA, ' - ', '-') AS DATA FROM TableName
```